# ' hated' and ' didn't like'?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

Differences between' hated' and ' didn't like'?

For example,

I used to work in an office. 
I hated that.

Which one is better to say and what are the grammatical and lexical differences between using each of them?

Comment: Please give a context, the phrases are different and would be used in different situations which makes your question very broad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, *hated* and *didn't like* are grammatically equivalent; where you can use one, you can use the other. Your example illustrates this:

> I used to work in an office. I hated that.
>   I used to work in an office. I didn't like that.

Both of these statements are grammatically valid.

The difference between *hated* and *didn't like* is one of meaning, not grammar. Hate is a much stronger feeling than mere dislike. For example, if I say "I hate my job!", you might infer that I will soon quit. Contrast that with "I don't like my job." In this case, I might quit, or maybe not. Both statements express dissatisfaction, but *hate* is emphatic, while *don't like* is marginal.

Comment: You hardly ever hear of someone killing another person because he "didn't like" him. Unless the killer was pretty drunk, of course.

Comment: I don't understand your point; can you elaborate?

Comment: I was agreeing with you, but being elliptical about it.. People do kill each other because they hate each other.